# How to get the data from one vector to another between specified data

Tags: c++, vector

I have vector which is having data Like

1 2 3 4 5 = 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 = 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ?

I want to get the data from start to first '=' match in one vector and from first '=' to next '=' match into another, similarly up to last occurrence

Last match of '=' to '?' also into one vector

I am trying with copy operation with string

```
       std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator it; 
       it = find (field.begin(), field.end(), '=');
       copy(field.begin() + 1, it, back_inserter(code));

       std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator it2;
       it2 = find (it, field.end(), '=');
       copy(field.begin(), it2, back_inserter(system_code));
```

I am getting data properly in above but is that any optimized way of doing this?

In above code I have to take iterator each time for last reference and not looking optimized way of solution

Comment: Unless you're using a very old compiler, you can declare a variable with auto, letting the compiler deduce the actual type: `auto it = std::find(field.begin(), field.end(), '=')`. Apart from this, there is an error in your second copy (`field.begin()` should be replace by `it` unless your description is false), and in the first one I don't see why you add `1`to `field.begin()`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t measured it and things can be made to be equivalent (at substantially more effort for the standard library implementer) but I would expect that the following approach is more effective:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> code(field.begin() + 1, it);
```

This approach lends itself to allocating enough space and then `std::copy()`ing from array to array. Using `std::back_inserter()` most likely ends up inserting individual elements (unless the library writer has implemented a special version of `std::copy()` for situations like that). That in turn is harder for the optimizer to see through.